# Import custom cordova plugin to mobile first 8.1 react js project

Tags: reactjs, cordova, mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I used the command cordova plugin add [custom_plugin_path] into my mobile first 8.1 react js project.

But when I try to call the cordova.exec for the added plugin, it throws error that cordova is undefined. May I know how to call the plugin in jsx?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this on cordova platform browser, or by running the react app in your browser?
Cordova will not be available in the browser.

Did you try testing it on a virtual/real device?